# Java Spring 400 bad request only on production

Tags: spring, httpclient, http-status-code-400

I run this simplified code. It works fine on the development machine and postman. When I export the jar into my remote server, it throws a bad request error when it runs.

Also, this error happens all of a sudden so it would seem something has changed from the data provider but nevertheless it is strange that it works on one computer locally but not on the remote one.

No major changes/update happened on my remote server. I have tried to add some headers also to specify JSON format but it did not change the outcome.

What else can I do? Any tips to what to look for?

P.S : the API key is public

```java
String  query = "https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/MCD.US?api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX"; 
        
System.out.println(query);

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(new URI(query))
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .GET()
        .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient()
        .send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

System.out.println(response.body());

while(true){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Response

```
> https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/MCD.US?api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX
> <html> <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head> <body>
> <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
> <hr><center>nginx/1.19.10</center> </body> </html>
```

Comment: check your server logs, they should provide more details about the error... then [edit] your question and add the stacktrace to it

Comment: @blurfus can you please detail a little more your suggestion even though you might think this is trivial. Do you mean try to log the HttpResponse?

Comment: Have you tried with HTTP version 2? Not sure if the server supports that. Also your code doesn't match your output. Your URL is missing a `?` whilst it is in your output.

Comment: In your remote server, where you are running your code, you can check to confirm that the request you are sending is exactly the same as in the other (dev machine, postman) environments where it does work.  You will need to log stuff to the server and see what the differences are.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the httpClient from

```
private final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
```

to

```
private static final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()     
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))     
            .build();
```

has solved the problem somehow